# Unable to merge Primary and Logical paritions

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm trying to increase the size of my C: drive(boot)
I want to reduce the size of my D drive and merge the 
unallocated partition to C drive. I've tried the Disk
Management tool in Windows 7, but that didn't work. 
I'm using EaseUS, but still can't get it to work since
the successive partitions are with file system
"Other".

How do I deal with this scenario?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, as D is logical drive in extended partition and C is primary partition. If both partitions are primary or both are secondary, it is possible. You can only have 4 primary partitions or 3 primary and 1 extended partition for creating logical partitions which seems to be your case. You can try this. delete one of the logical drive, shrink extended partition and then extend C drive.
If you shrink D drive and space is made, you can use GParted, Partition Magic or any other partitioning tool to move all the partitions to the right, hence the free space will be moved to the left.

Comment: I tried shrinking D drive since I don't want to delete D drive. This created an empty space, but to the right of D drive. 

The partitions with file type "other"(extended partition) cannot be shrinked.
How do I get this empty space to the left of the D partition? This would allow me to extend the extended partition eventually.

Comment: On a side note, you can convert an extended partition into a primary partition.

I'm referring to using MBR-based format...  I'm not yet sure about GPT format.

I'm also not saying that this can be done with a few mouse clicks in the Disk Management GUI.  However, with the right software, I can look on the hard drive for specific values, and change those values.  I could create a D: which is a primary drive. Also, since D: is the first drive in the extended partition, the extended partition could start at the E: rather easily. I know I'm not saying how; I'm just sharing feasible possibilities.

Comment: As a quick follow-up comment to my previous comment: some of the possibilities I mention can be done with software that can be quite dangerous when things are done improperly, so don't do any of that carelessly.  For any actually important data, the proper procedure is to back up the hard drive before making such changes.

Comment: Backup essential data make a hybrid table  (gpt with a fake mbr) then play as you wish partition )   then you can backup  merely reinstalling bootloader post restore to take new uuids and such